# How to Reverse the words of only selected table cells using macro in Ms Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, tablecell, word-table

I have a code that works with the **selected running text** but **not** working with the selected table cells.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim oWords As Words
Dim oWord As Range
Set oWords = Selection.Range.Words
For i = 1 To oWords.Count Step 1

    Set oWord = oWords(i)

    ''Make sure the word range doesn't include a space
    Do While oWord.Characters.Last.text = " "
        Call oWord.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1)
    Loop

    Debug.Print "'" & oWord.text & "'"
    oWord.text = StrReverse(oWord.text)

Next i
```

I also have the code to extract each cell value but how to modify this to run on selected table cells.
**First Code:**

```
Sub Demo()
Dim x As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Tbl As Table
Set Tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  For i = 1 To Tbl.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To Tbl.Columns.Count
        x = Tbl.Cell(i, j).Range.Text
Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

**Second Code:**

```
Sub testTable()
Dim arr As Variant
Dim intcols As Integer
Dim lngRows As Long
Dim lngCounter As Long

lngRows = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count
intcols = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns.Count
arr = Split(Replace(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Text, Chr(7), ""), Chr(13))
For rw = 1 To lngRows
    For col = 1 To intcols
        Debug.Print "Table 1, Row " & rw & ", column " & col; " data is " & arr(lngCounter)
        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
    Next
    lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: See if the Answer in this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532952/reading-date-from-table-in-word-without-additional-characters/49533912#49533912. You can use the `TrimCellText` function with your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that you should be able to adapt to your purpose.

```
Sub FindWordsInTableCells()
    Dim doc As Word.Document, rng As Word.Range
    Dim tbl As Word.Table, rw As Word.Row, cl As Word.Cell
    Dim i As Integer, iRng As Word.Range
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
        For Each rw In tbl.rows
            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                Set rng = cl.Range
                rng.MoveEnd Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=-1
                For i = 1 To rng.words.Count
                    Set iRng = rng.words(i)
                    Debug.Print iRng.Text
                Next i
            Next cl
        Next rw
    Next tbl
End Sub
```

If you want to only use cells that are currently selected then use this adaptation of the above routine.

```
Sub FindWordsInSelectedTableCells()
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim cl As Word.Cell
    Dim i As Integer, iRng As Word.Range
    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
        For Each cl In Selection.Cells
            Set rng = cl.Range
            rng.MoveEnd Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=-1
            For i = 1 To rng.words.Count
                Set iRng = rng.words(i)
                rng.Select
                'insert your word manipulation code here
                Debug.Print Selection.Text
            Next i
        Next cl
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, But this solves my one problem, is there any solution I can run this on only selected columns.

Comment: If i run this only on selected colum, then run time will decrese and **second** i have to itegrate this with the above reverse word code so i thinks if i go with each cell then every word will be reversed. Do you have any solution, how can i **integrate** these **two code**.

Comment: @MAhad, I have added another example of how the code would look when looking at only selected cells in a table.

Comment: kindly help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53820982/how-can-i-keep-the-selected-tables-cells-selected-after-i-run-the-macro

Comment: @ Rich Michaels i got one more problem with the above selection macro. If i want to run the same macro twice, i lost the selected cells..but i need the selected portion selected after the selection.