# How can i keep the selected tables cells, selected after i run the macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word, selection, tablecell

When i run the below mention macro to reverse the selected table cells words, the macro deselect the selected cells after its first run. I want the selected cells selected after this macro run so that i can call the second macro on the same selection.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim cl As Word.Cell
Dim i As Integer, iRng As Word.Range
Dim oWords As Words
Dim oWord As Range

If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    For Each cl In Selection.Cells
        Set rng = cl.Range
        rng.MoveEnd Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=-1
        For i = 1 To rng.Words.Count
            Set iRng = rng.Words(i)
            'rng.Select

            Set oWord = iRng
            Do While oWord.Characters.Last.Text = " "
                Call oWord.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1)
            Loop
            Debug.Print "'" & oWord.Text & "'"
            oWord.Text = StrReverse(oWord.Text)

            Debug.Print Selection.Text

        Next i
    Next cl
End If

End Sub
Sub Align()

'Selection.RtlPara
 Selection.LtrPara

 End Sub

 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

 Call Align
 Call CommandButton1_Click
 Call Comma_Remove
 Call CommandButton1_Click

 End Sub

 Sub Comma_Remove()


Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ","
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

[You can see the attached Pic for more clearification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot9tS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to run the second macro separately? You could just add at the end of your macro to call the second one.

You probably want to pass the selection to the second macro something like this:

** EDIT: added a bit more clarity (i hope) **

```
Sub firstMacro(selection)

'' Do stuff with Selection
Debug.Print "This is the first macro and address of selection is: " & selection.Address

End Sub

Sub secondMacro(selection)

'' Do more stuff with Selection
Debug.Print "This is the second macro and address of selection is: " & selection.Address

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Call firstMacro(selection)

    Call secondMacro(selection)

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click(selection) '<--- THIS IS WRONG

End Sub
```

Comment: .duplicate is your friend here.

Comment: I passed the selection and now i am getting error..!!

Comment: I can't help further without knowing what the error is, and what the content of your second macro is.

Comment: I add the remaining code now you can understand what i am trying to achieve. For more info first two Call macro run perfectly but last two only work on the only one cell in which cursor is blinking.

Comment: You still didn't said what error you are getting... and would have helped if you've made the modifications I`ve suggested so I can correct what you are doing wrong... Ofcourse, there are better ways to achieve what you are doing there, but my suggestion is the simplest fix i can think off.

Comment: @DarXyde The error i got when i did the modification is "Procedure declaration does not match description of the event or procedure having the same name"

Comment: I believe you are trying to pass the parameter (Selection) to one of the **Click** buttons, hence you are getting that error. Pretty sure those subs that respond to Click events, do not take a parameter. You should rename your sub to something else before trying to pass a parameter in, and if you really need to have the routine on click as well, just call it from within the Click sub. I`ll edit my post above for more clarification.

Comment: Now i did the necessary changes and the when i run the macro if one page contain two different tables and if i only selected the few values of the first table, but macro run on all the values and even on the second table values as well.